# force:refreshView erroring out

Tags: lightning-aura-components

Controller.js

```
({
doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
    helper.getData(component, event);
 },
})
```

Helper.js

```
  getData : function(component, event){

    var action = component.get('c.loadData');
    action.setStorable();
    action.setParams({"acctID" : component.get("v.recordId")

                     });

    action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
        var state = response.getState();
        if (state === "SUCCESS") {

            var returnObj   = response.getReturnValue();
            component.set("v.data", returnObj);
            //$A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire(); --> This line is failing, stating cannnot access property of fire
         } else if (state === "ERROR") {
            var errors = response.getError();
            console.error(errors);
        }
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
}
```

I'm getting an error at that line in appbuilder stating that it cannot access property of null, I'm trying to place this component as a tab (next to record detail tab). Anyone know how to fix this?

$A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire();

Comment: It is not failing for me.

Comment: You mentioned two different error messages, `cannot access property of null` and `cannnot access property of fire`. Which one is it? Can you post the exact message you are seeing?

Comment: Uncaught Action failed: :clientRecordDetail$controller$onChange [Cannot read property 'fire' of null]
Callback failed

Comment: please share also your markup